# Is there a way to make a discord py bot stop an instance of a loop in cog by a command

Tags: python, discord.py

I have this bot with with this and i am wondering if i can make a command to stop one of the instances of the loop that is working on the server which the command is done.

The code is making a new loop every time the command is run but there is no way to stop it once it runs

```
class TaskHandler(commands.Cog):
  def __init__(self, bot):
    self.bot = bot
    self._tasks = [] # Empty list, holds all the loops. You can also use a dict ifyou want to differentiate the tasks somehow

  async def static_loop(self, arg1, arg2):
        # This is the function that will be 'looping'

    print(arg1, arg2)
    arg2 = client.get_channel(int(arg2.replace('<', '').replace('>', '').replace('#', '')))
    url = f"https://api.pray.zone/v2/times/today.json?city={arg1}"
    data = requests.get(url).json()
    print(data)
    
    print(data.get('results')["datetime"][0]['times'].get("Fajr"))

    print(data.get('results').get('location').get('local_offset'))

    nowhour = datetime.now().strftime("%H")
    nowhour = int(nowhour) 
    nowhour = nowhour + data.get('results').get('location').get('local_offset')
    nowhour = int(nowhour)
    if nowhour >= 24:
      nowhour = nowhour - 24
    elif nowhour < 0:
      nowhour = nowhour + 24
      nowhour = int(nowhour)
    elif nowhour < 10 :
      nowhour = "0" + str(nowhour)
    nowminute = datetime.now().strftime("%M")
    now = str(nowhour) + ":" + nowminute
    if now == str(data.get('results')["datetime"][0]['times'].get("Fajr")):
      await arg2.send(f'Its Fajr Time In {arg1}! ||@everyone||')
    elif now == str(data.get('results')["datetime"][0]['times'].get("Dhuhr")):
      await arg2.send(f'Its Dhuhr Time In {arg1}! ||@everyone||')
    elif now == str(data.get('results')["datetime"][0]['times'].get("Asr")):
      await arg2.send(f'Its Asr Time In {arg1}! ||@everyone||')
    elif now == str(data.get('results')["datetime"][0]['times'].get("Maghrib")):
      await arg2.send(f'Its Maghrib Time In {arg1}! ||@everyone||')
    elif now == str(data.get('results')["datetime"][0]['times'].get("Isha")):
      await arg2.send(f'Its Isha Time In {arg1}! ||@everyone||')
  

    print(now)
    print(self._tasks)




  def task_launcher(self, arg1, arg2, **interval): 
    """Creates new instances of `tasks.Loop`"""
    # Creating the task
    new_task = tasks.loop(**interval)(self.static_loop) # You can also pass a static interval and/or count
    # Starting the task
    new_task.start(arg1, arg2)
    self._tasks.append(new_task)
  
  @commands.command()
  async def setup(self, ctx, arg1, arg2):
    
    try:
      url = f"https://api.pray.zone/v2/times/today.json?city={arg1}"
      data = requests.get(url).json()
      self.task_launcher(arg1, arg2, seconds=60)
      await ctx.send("Done")
    except:
      await ctx.send("City name is not valid")
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [stopping a task discord.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64463973/stopping-a-task-discord-py)

Comment: @DaniloMercadoOudalova the solution you linked uses `task.cancel()`, I just wanna point out that since the original answer `task.stop()` was added to discord.py to wait until the task has completed before stopping.

Comment: @DaniloMercadoOudalova how do i make it stop one of the tasks when there are multiple instances of the loop running